# Macro: Drawing border line to group data within the same date

Tags: excel, vba

Actually I'm new for using macro, and I faced some difficulty for drawing the border line to group all the data with same date. My code is shown below here, appreciate if anyone able to help me up for this. And the result should be displayed as attached pictured.

========================================================================================

```
Public i As Integer

Sub GetCellValue()

Dim rngEnd As Range
NumRows = Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Range("A3").Select

For i = 3 To NumRows

If Cells(i, 1).Value <> Cells(i + 1, 1).Value Then
   Call BorderCode
   Cells(i + 1, 1).Select
End If

Next

End Sub


Sub BorderCode()

Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(i, 11)).Select
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
```

## End Sub

Comment: Are all dates in column A? In other words, are you trying to draw a border around cells in column A that have the same date?

Answer (score 1):

If dates are in column A, and all dates are already sorted, you can use `Do...Loop` to work its way through all cells in column A, and group accordingly.

Also, I'd recommend using the `Range.BorderAround` method. This is a lot cleaner, faster, and it avoids having to use `Selection` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select/10717999#10717999)).

So, here's an idea of how you could do this.

```
Dim r1 As Byte, r2 As Byte
Dim lr As Long
'prime the loop
r1 = 1 'first row pointer
r2 = r1 'look-ahead row pointer
lr = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1 'the first row with
'a blank line, so the loop knows when to stop.

'loop only in the data, stop when a blank line encountered
Do While r1 < lr
  'figure out how many days are together
  Do While Cells(r2 + 1, 1).Value = Cells(r1, 1).Value
    r2 = r2 + 1
  Loop
  'draw border around similiar ranges
  Range(Cells(r1, 1), Cells(r2, 1)).BorderAround _
    ColorIndex:=xlColorIndexAutomatic
  'prime for the next Do...Loop iteration
  r1 = r2 + 1
  r2 = r1
Loop
```